# "using" in the struct definition

Tags: c++, templates, struct, typename

I'm very newbie in C++. I got the code about the finite state machine on github. There are things in the code I don't understand. For example, I don't know why the use `using` in the  struct ,and what is purpose of the line `typename _state_instance<S>::value_type _state_instance<S>::value`

```
  struct _state_instance
  {
    using value_type = S;
    using type = _state_instance<S>;
    static S value;
  };

  template<typename S>
  typename _state_instance<S>::value_type _state_instance<S>::value;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Refer to a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). The basics can be found in the books mentioned in the above list.

Comment: BTW this small part of code is a code smell. Looks like some stupid attempt to for singleton template. What is the source of this code? I would not trust its author.

Comment: @MarekR This seems like [tinyfsm](https://github.com/digint/tinyfsm/blob/master/include/tinyfsm.hpp).